# WP 4.7 in_category change?

Tags: categories, taxonomy

Since upgrade to 4.7, this code line is no longer returning:

```
function foo(bar){
    global $post;
    if(in_category("my-test-category", $post)) return;
    echo "Not in my-test-category";
}
```

Did something change with the in_category filter?

Note: "my-test-category" is a child of "Uncategorized"

Comment: I don't think so. it looks like `foo()` will always return `null`, no matter the `in_category()` check.

Comment: I can get foo to echo anything, except this if should return but doesn't. Why do you say always null return?

Comment: Does `in_category()` work outside the function and where do you use it (context) ? Can't you skip the second `$post` argument, if you want the global `$post` object, because `get_post( null )` will try to use the global post object if it exists?

Comment: I've found the issue. I'm running a filter on list_terms_exclusions to remove children of "Uncategorized". Possible this filter was not run on in_category() prior to 4.7 and possibly back as far as 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue. I've been running a filter on **list_terms_exclusions** specifically to remove all children of "Uncategorized" from appearing on the public website.

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'my_list_terms_exclusions',10,2);
```

However, using in_category() still returned matches on those categories, which was exactly what I wanted. I needed to hide those categories from appearing in category listings, but I still needed to know when a specific post had one or more of those categories present. And so I was able to use in_category() for that purpose.

This technique has worked fine for as long as I remember until 4.7

However, as of 4.7 (and possibly before), the in_category() function gets filtered by list_terms_exclusions. So it no longer returns any of my categories under Uncategorized.

Comment: I'm still trying to determine which release changed this so that "in_category()" is filtered by list_terms_exclusions